# error Cannot open include file ui_HelloWorldGUI.h (GUI) when create new qt application

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am learning about Qt framewk and Visual studio, vs Qt Extension 2019. 
first time, i created new project Qt Application GUI, my program compiled good,
but next time, When i create new project again then issue these errors.
i have found these topic, but i dont , i think qt extension dont make ui_HelloWorldGui.h, help me.

```
 #pragma once
#include "ui_HelloWorldGUI.h"

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>

class HelloWorldGUI : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    HelloWorldGUI(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

private:
    Ui::HelloWorldGUIClass ui;
};
```

C1083 Cannot open include file: 'ui_HelloWorldGUI.h': No such file or directory

E1696 cannot open source file "ui_HelloWorldGUI.h"

E0276 name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name

Comment: did you set the path to your Qt installation in the Qt Extension?

Comment: @PeterT i added the path in Qt Extension,

Comment: Could you please update how you created the new project, step-by-step.
Can you attach other files as well? e.g. project file.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like missing HelloWorldGUI.ui in pro file.